# Is there an easy way to make a clickable border for a card in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a way to highlight the border when I hover on it and I can click on the border, which gives me a starting point to draw lines. (Something we often see in a workflow app, a plus sign on the border when we hover on the border)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple way to card border color change on taping

```
class StackOverflow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackOverflowState createState() => _StackOverflowState();
}

class _StackOverflowState extends State<StackOverflow> {
  Color borderColor = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tap to Toggle Border Color'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // Handle the tap event here
            setState(() {
              // Toggle the border color on each tap
              borderColor =
                  (borderColor == Colors.black) ? Colors.blue : Colors.black;
            });
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 100,
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(color: borderColor, width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Tap",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```